# Can't save .xcasset file in Visual Studio

Tags: ios, windows, visual-studio, xcasset

I am making an app with Xamarin.iOS in Visual Studio on Windows. When uploading the app to the App Store I get following warning:

> Missing App Store Icon - iOS Apps must include a 1024x1024px App Store Icon in PNG format. Without providing the icon in the Asset Catalog or via App Store Connect, apps cannot be submitted for App Review or Beta App Review. Refer to https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/app-icon/ for more information.

Fine, I can add an icon of that size to the `.appiconset` in `Assets.xcasset`. When I then try to save `Assets.xcasset` I get following error:

> Collection has been modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

If I try to build the project without saving I get:

> The method or operation is not implemented.

If I close `Assets.xcassets` without saving, the changes I made are lost (obviously).

What am I doing wrong here? How should I add an App Store Icon of size 1024x1024 to the asset catalog so that I can save?

Answer (score 2):

Was running into this issue today.  This may not be the official fix/answer, but what worked for me was deleting all of the existing Assets and starting from scratch.  After that I was able to add assets without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was: **SAVE THE ASSET AFTER YOU RENAME IT - BEFORE UPLOADING FILES.**

When creating a new asset by pressing the add icon, it gives a default name. Then you normally rename it and start adding the files to the renamed asset (except it's not renamed yet in the file directory because you didn't save the rename first). When you try to save it, it can give this error.